# How to safely fix an AWOL ambari system user?

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I'm a student working on a test cluster, consisting of around 25 hosts. We installed using Ambari and have FreeIpa running on a host as a dns and ldap server. The rest are typical Hadoop
infrastructure. Hive was failing and I wondered whether the db connection parameters used during the Ambari installation were incorrect and I tried to find a way to re-run the db connection process. I didn't get anywhere and it was late so I left it, ambari interface working.

Next morning, ambari webUI seems to be down. I thought that maybe the webserver needed restarted so I tried the following:

```
[akidd@dw ~]$ sudo ambari-server start
Using python /usr/bin/python
Starting ambari-server
ERROR: Exiting with exit code 1.
REASON: Unable to detect a system user for Ambari Server.
- If this is a new setup, then run the "ambari-server setup" command to create the user
- If this is an upgrade of an existing setup, run the "ambari-server upgrade" command.
Refer to the Ambari documentation for more information on setup and upgrade.
```

Can anyone help me to understand what could have happened?

If I run `ambari-server setup` will the existing cluster be ok assuming I create everything like for like with how it was originally?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@user3535074  You should try to start it with the user that installed it.

If you do run ambari-server setup as current user,  remember to choose No the following options:

```
Customize user account for ambari-server daemon [y/n] (n)? n
Do you want to change Oracle JDK [y/n] (n)? n
Enter advanced database configuration [y/n] (n)? n
```

More info on the following post, including how to backup ambari database before running setup again:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Ambari-server-failed-to-start-after-system-reboot-Below-is/td-p/203806